# Помогите найти ошибку при выводе дат через JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Имеется код для вывода месяцев(начиная с нынешнего +11), после в зависимости от выбранного месяца выводятся даты на этот месяц(в марте с нынешней даты до конца марта, т.е. с 18 по 31ое, В Апреле с 1го по 30ое и тд), тут и заключается проблема, жуткие не состыковки:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  Data = new Date();
  Year = Data.getFullYear();
  Month = Data.getMonth();
  Day = Data.getDate();

  var arr_month = [
    'Январь',
    'Февраль',
    'Март',
    'Апрель',
    'Май',
    'Июнь',
    'Июль',
    'Август',
    'Сентябрь',
    'Октябрь',
    'Ноябрь',
    'Декабрь',
  ];


  var elem = document.getElementById('scrollbar1');

  for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    var new_month = new Date(Year, Month + i, Day).getMonth();
    var label = document.createElement('label');
    label.className = 'item01';
    label.name = ('item01_label_name');
    $(label).attr('id', 'item01_label');
    var snap = document.createElement('snap');
    snap.className = 'item01_snap';
    snap.innerText = arr_month[new_month];
    var inp = document.createElement('input');
    inp.setAttribute('type', 'radio');
    inp.value = new_month;
    $(inp).attr('id', 'item01_radio');
    inp.name = ('item01_radio');
    $(inp).attr('required', true);

    label.appendChild(snap);
    label.appendChild(inp);
    elem.appendChild(label);
  }

  $('input:radio[name="item01_radio"]').change(function() {
    $('input:radio[name="item01_radio"]').parent().removeClass('label_main_selected');
    $('input:radio[name="item01_radio"]:checked').parent().toggleClass('label_main_selected');
    var month_check = $('input:radio[name="item01_radio"]:checked').val();

    if (month_check == Month) {

      var days = new Date(Year, (Data.getMonth() + 1), 0).getDate();
      var days_remained = days - Day;
      response = days_remained;
    } else {
      response = new Date(Year, (month_check + 1), 0).getDate();
    }

    document.getElementById('scrollbar2').innerHTML = "";
    var elem = document.getElementById('scrollbar2');
    console.log(response);
    for (i = 1; i < response + 1; i++) {
      if (month_check == Month) {
        new_date = new Date(Year, Data.getMonth(), Day + i).getDate();
        full_date = new Date(Year, Data.getMonth(), Day + i);
      } else {
        new_date = new Date(Year, month_check, i).getDate();
        full_date = new Date(Year, month_check, i);
      }
      var label = document.createElement('label');
      label.className = 'item11';
      label.name = ('item11_label_name');
      $(label).attr('id', 'item11_label');
      var snap = document.createElement('snap');
      snap.className = 'item11_snap';
      snap.innerText = new_date;
      var inp = document.createElement('input');
      inp.setAttribute('type', 'radio');
      inp.value = full_date;
      $(inp).attr('id', 'item11_radio');
      inp.name = ('item11_radio');
      $(inp).attr('required', true);

      label.appendChild(snap);
      label.appendChild(inp);
      elem.appendChild(label);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

       <main>
        <div class="grid_container">
            <div class = "wrapper">
                <div class="item0" id="scrollbar1">
                    
                </div>
                <div class="item1" id="scrollbar2">
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
```

1. Переменная `full_date` вроде бы показывает правильный год и
   месяц *Sun Apr 05 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (Москва, стандартное время)*
   Но если вы посмотрите, то в 5 Апреля - это четверг, а не воскресенье.
2. Если развилка `if(month_check == Month)` идет на *else*, то переменная response для месяцев Апрель, Май, Июнь, Июль, Август, Сентябрь , Октябрь будет соответственно равна 31,31,31,31,30,30,31,31 (вообще там с Апреля начинается цикл 4 по 31 2 по 30 и тд), что не соответствует количеству дней в этих месяцах.

Знаю, вопрос большой, но может кто то сразу заметит ошибку. Можете критиковать код, только просьба адекватно, указывая на плохой тон и на альтернативные способы решения!!!

Comment: Куда мы должны посмотреть? Добавьте html в пример.

Comment: @igor Добавил html.

Comment: "full_date вроде бы показывает" - Вы ожидаете, что кто-то будет отладчиком идти по Вашему коду?

Comment: @igor если бы на stack Overflow были бы пронумерованы строки, то в таком случае я бы написал, что это за строка. А какие альтернативы?

Comment: Выводить эти данные на страницу.

Comment: `РњР°РЅРёРєСЋСЂ` - ?

Comment: Сидел с телефона и взял файл html из ВК, тот видимо русский текст поменял) От этого логика выводи дат все равно не поменяется. Все эти данные итак выводятся на страницу( хранятся в value item 11, это можно увидеть через «исследовать страницу»).

Comment: Поправьте **РњР°РЅРёРєСЋСЂ**, пожалуйста. И напишите в вопросе, что это код должен делать?

Comment: `new Date(Year, Month + i, Day)` - при создании даты таким образом номер месяца начинается с нуля, то есть 0 - Январь.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko `Month = Data.getMonth();`, сомнений насчет вывода месяцев у меня нет

Comment: Все еще не понятно, что вы хотите добиться. Что данный код должен выводить?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Имеется код для вывода месяцев(начиная с нынешнего +11), после в зависимости от выбранного месяца выводятся даты на этот месяц(в марте с нынешней даты до конца марта, т.е. с 18 по 31ое, В Апреле с 1го по 30ое и тд)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка была в неявном преобразовании типов. Переменная `month_check` была строкового типа.

И при выполнении `response = new Date(Year, (month_check + 1), 0).getDate();` делалось не то, что вы ожидали. Выполнялось что-то вроде `response = new Date(2020, '21', 0).getDate();`, при `month_check = '2'`.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  Data = new Date();
  Year = Data.getFullYear();
  Month = Data.getMonth();
  Day = Data.getDate();

  var arr_month = [
    'Январь',
    'Февраль',
    'Март',
    'Апрель',
    'Май',
    'Июнь',
    'Июль',
    'Август',
    'Сентябрь',
    'Октябрь',
    'Ноябрь',
    'Декабрь',
  ];


  var elem = document.getElementById('scrollbar1');

  for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    var new_month = new Date(Year, Month + i, Day).getMonth();
    var label = document.createElement('label');
    label.className = 'item01';
    label.name = ('item01_label_name');
    $(label).attr('id', 'item01_label');
    var snap = document.createElement('span');
    snap.className = 'item01_snap';
    snap.innerText = arr_month[new_month];
    var inp = document.createElement('input');
    inp.setAttribute('type', 'radio');
    inp.value = new_month;
    $(inp).attr('id', 'item01_radio');
    inp.name = ('item01_radio');
    $(inp).attr('required', true);

    label.appendChild(snap);
    label.appendChild(inp);
    elem.appendChild(label);
  }

  $('input:radio[name="item01_radio"]').change(function() {
    $('input:radio[name="item01_radio"]').parent().removeClass('label_main_selected');
    $('input:radio[name="item01_radio"]:checked').parent().toggleClass('label_main_selected');
    // вот тут ошибка month_check - имела строковое значение текущего месяца
    var month_check = +$('input:radio[name="item01_radio"]:checked').val();

    if (month_check == Month) {

      var days = new Date(Year, (Data.getMonth() + 1), 0).getDate();
      var days_remained = days - Day;
      response = days_remained;
    } else {
      response = new Date(Year, (month_check + 1), 0).getDate();
    }

    document.getElementById('scrollbar2').innerHTML = "";
    var elem = document.getElementById('scrollbar2');
    console.log(response);
    for (i = 1; i < response + 1; i++) {
      if (month_check == Month) {
        new_date = new Date(Year, Data.getMonth(), Day + i).getDate();
        full_date = new Date(Year, Data.getMonth(), Day + i);
      } else {
        new_date = new Date(Year, month_check, i).getDate();
        full_date = new Date(Year, month_check, i);
      }
      var label = document.createElement('label');
      label.className = 'item11';
      label.name = ('item11_label_name');
      $(label).attr('id', 'item11_label');
      var snap = document.createElement('snap');
      snap.className = 'item11_snap';
      snap.innerText = new_date;
      var inp = document.createElement('input');
      inp.setAttribute('type', 'radio');
      inp.value = full_date;
      $(inp).attr('id', 'item11_radio');
      inp.name = ('item11_radio');
      $(inp).attr('required', true);

      label.appendChild(snap);
      label.appendChild(inp);
      elem.appendChild(label);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<main>
  <div class="grid_container">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="item0" id="scrollbar1">

      </div>
      <div class="item1" id="scrollbar2">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: В таком случае почему у меня через `console.log(month_check)` выводился именно номер месяца (0-11)?

Comment: @Kirzzz потому что вы не поняли причину ошибки. Выведите через консоль `console.log(month_check + 1)`